# Problema con $.post al enviar un formulario no va al archivo que deseo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

estoy intentando que cuando pulso un botón vaya a una función y esta me recoja el valor del botón (de momento a mano ya que estoy probando), después enviar ese dato por post a otro fichero y ese fichero que me cree una carpeta por ejemplo. El problema es que creo que no entra en el archivo que debe de crear la carpeta y no entiendo el por que. Muchas gracias de antemano. Dejo el código.

Botón:

```
<button type="button" onclick="mostrarLs();" id="botonMostrarLs" value="213">Botón prueba</button>
```

Función:

```
    function mostrarLs() {
    var id = $('#botonMostrarLs').val();
    console.log('id de la sede: '.id);
    $.post("prueba_comandos.php", {id: id}, console.log('procesamiento finalizado'));

}
```

Archivo con comandos:

```
    <script>
    console.log('entra en el fichero de prueba de comandos');
</script>
<?
$accion = $_POST['id'];

if(!system('mkdir /var/www/sigilaV2/html/Centros/prueba_comando_'.$accion)) {
    ?>
    <script>
        console.log('Fallo al crear la carpeta');
    </script>
    <?
}else{
    ?>
    <script>
        console.log('La carpeta se a creado correctamente.');
    </script>
    <? 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En vía el valor al llamar a la función en tu botón por ejemplo

```
<button type="button" onclick="mostrarLs(213);" id="botonMostrarLs">Botón prueba</button>
```

Y lo recibes con la variable ID en tu función así

```
function mostrarLs(id) {
    
    $.post("prueba_comandos.php", {id: id}, console.log('procesamiento finalizado'));

}
```

Comment: Te comento amigo, entrar si que me entra en el archivo. El problema que tengo ahora es que no me funciona system() ni tampoco shell_excec(), el id me llega bien por que lo e comprobado. El problema como digo son system() o shell_exec() que no me ejecutan los comandos.

Comment: Bueno así probando veo que un pwd o un ls si que lo ejecuta pero por alguna razon el mkdir no...

Comment: @Ismael si unos comandos funcionan y otros no, entonces es problema de ese comando. En el caso de `mkdir` puede estar fallando por varios motivos: La ruta es incorrecta; el archivo ya existe; no tienes permisos para crear archivos/directorios en esa ruta, etc. Es algo que debes verificar en tu contexto. Ayudará que revises el log de errores, en el cual habrá casi seguro una descripción más exacta de lo que está ocurriendo.

Comment: Gracias amigo, era por el tema de los permisos de la carpeta.